# Not receive response from paypal on success

Tags: php, laravel, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have integrate paypal with my Laravel application. I'm able to make payment successfully from Paypal, but after successful payment I'm not able to receive any type of response in my site.

My code is as below:

```
public function aCoolFunction(CreateDistrictRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->only('city_id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude');
    $district = $this->districtRepository->create($data);

    $payment = 'sandbox';
    $values = [
        'charest'       => 'utf-8',
        'lc'            => 'US',
        'cmd'           => '_xclick',
        'amount'        => $product->price, // PRICE
        'business'      => 'test-facilitator@gmail.com', // PAYPAL EMAIL
        'item_name'     => $product->name, // NAME
        'item_number'   => $product->id, // ITEM ID
        'currency_code' => 'USD',
        'no_note'       => '0',
        'tax_rate'      => 0, // 0- TO NOT ADD ANY FEES
        'no_shipping'   => 1, // NO ADDRESS
        'rm'            => '1',
        'page_style'    => 'paypal',
        'custom'        => '1', // ANY VALUES TO RETURN IT AFTER PAYMENT SUCCESS
        'return'        => url('payment-status'), // RETURN - MUST BE A VALID URL
        'cancel_return' => url('payment-cancel'),
        'notify_url'    => url('payment-ipn') // IPN PAYPAL - CHECK IF IS PAID
    ];
    $pay_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    // CREATE $payment TO CHECK IF IS SANDBOX or LIVE - FROM CONFIG FILE FOR EXAMPLE
    if ($payment == 'sandbox') :
        $pay_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    endif;

    return view('paypalpayment', ['pay_url' => $pay_url, 'values' => $values]);
}

public function paymentInfo(Request $request)
{
    $myfile = fopen("paypalog.txt", "w") or die('Cannot open file:  ' . $my_file);
    $data = 'Transaction id = ' . $request;
    fwrite($myfile, $data);
    if ($request->tx)
    {
        if ($payment = Payment::where('transaction_id', $request->tx)->first())
        {
            $payment_id = $payment->id;
        }
        else
        {
            $payment = new Payment;
            $payment->item_number = $request->item_number;
            $payment->transaction_id = $request->tx;
            $payment->currency_code = $request->cc;
            $payment->payment_status = $request->st;
            $payment->save();
            $payment_id = $payment->id;
        }

        return 'Pyament has been done and your payment id is : ' . $payment_id;
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Payment has failed';
    }
}

public function payment_success(Request $req)
{
    $myfile = fopen("paypalog1.txt", "w") or die('Cannot open file:  ' . $my_file);
    $data = 'Transaction id = ' . $request->tx;
    fwrite($myfile, $data);
}
```

from above code `paymentinfo()` is call in success or failure of payment from paypal. but here I'am not able to get any type of response from Paypal regarding payment.

This are my routes

```
Route::get('payment-status',array('as'=>'payment.status','uses'=>'PaymentController@paymentInfo'));    
  Route::get('payment',array('as'=>'payment','uses'=>'PaymentController@payment'));

Route::get('payment-cancel', function () {
   return 'Payment has been canceled';
});

 Route::get('payment-success' , 'PaymentController@payment_success');
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, Please add your Routes too! I want to see theme :) - About Paypal payment of course.

Comment: I have added routes in question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

While dealing with PayPal you have to implement the `IPN` (Instant payment Notification) to get the status of the payment whether it is successful or failed.

For that you have to activate the IPN under the setting in your PayPal account and provide an url of your system to receive the IPN data, and that url must be of `post` type.

If I am not wrong, you have created this url for the same:

```
Route::get('payment-success' , 'PaymentController@payment_success');
```

but the issue is, it is of `get` type, so change it to 'post' and try again. If this url is not for the same purpose then create a url for the same.

**P.S.**: for testing purpose, PayPal provides an IPN simulator to test the same process, use that one it will be very helpful.

IPN simulator [reference](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/)

Comment: I have make change according to you have suggest but it gives me **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** error

Comment: Don't change `Route::get('payment-success' , 'PaymentController@payment_success');`, create another route for IPN, as a success route of get type is required for PayPal.

Comment: I have create new route for IPN , and updated my question with that method in **notify_url**. but still not get data from paypal properly.

Comment: And where is the `post` type route for `paymentInfo`

Comment: If i am adding post type route then it will give me same **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** error

Comment: is there any thing need to set in paypal account for IPN URL? i think that may be issue but i dont find any setting regarding this to specify IPN url.